# How to validate a field to have specific value only in AVRO Schema

Tags: java, avro

I am using Avro Schema to validate my schema is:

```
{
"name": "Example",
"type": "record",
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "custId",
    "type": "string" 
  },
{
    "name": "danger",
    "type": {
      "type": "enum",
      "symbols": [0,1,2,3],
      "name": "danger"
    }}
]
```

}

i have a requirement where i want field "danger" to have values 0,1,2,3 . If something else is given schema should not validate it. I know enum type are used for that but it allow only string.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: Enum names can only be strings, just like Java enums... Avro doesn't have validation logic like this; you would need to build that into your deserializer